# Standard Bottom Sheet with snap to STATE_EXPANDED, STATE_HALF_EXPANDED and STATE_COLLAPSED

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Is it possible to make a [Standard Bottom Sheet](https://m2.material.io/components/sheets-bottom/android#standard-bottom-sheet) snap to these three states?

- `STATE_EXPANDED`
- `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`
- `STATE_COLLAPSED`

By default it already snaps to `STATE_EXPANDED` and `STATE_COLLAPSED` but not to `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out how one can achieve it by reading `BottomSheetBehavior.java`.

If you read that class, you'll find the following snippet of code:

[image]

**As you can see, the code will only consider snapping to the `STATE_HALF_EXPANDED` state if `fitToContents` is equals to false.**
So setting this flag to `false` is the answer to the question.